# RealmError: Permission denied in /Users/jasonflax/Development/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 101

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, realm, permission-denied

```
class App : Application() {
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
Realm.init(this)
    val realmConfig = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .compactOnLaunch()
        .name("sms.realm")
        .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
        .migration(realmMigration)
        .schemaVersion(QkRealmMigration.SchemaVersion)
        .build()
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig)
    try {
        Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    } catch (e: RealmError){
        rebuildRealm(realmConfig)
    } catch (e: RealmFileException){
        rebuildRealm(realmConfig)
    }
}

private fun rebuildRealm(realmConfig: RealmConfiguration) {
    Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig)
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig)
}
}
```

> In Application Class I create the instance on Realm...

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.sms, PID: 10913
io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Permission denied in /Users/jasonflax/Development/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 101
at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.<init>(OsSharedRealm.java:171)
at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:241)
at io.realm.BaseRealm.<init>(BaseRealm.java:136)
at io.realm.BaseRealm.<init>(BaseRealm.java:103)
at io.realm.Realm.<init>(Realm.java:163)
at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:499)
at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:355)
at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:285)
at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:407)
at com.app.sms.repository.ConversationRepositoryImpl.getConversations(ConversationRepositoryImpl.kt:58)
at com.app.sms.repository.ConversationRepository$DefaultImpls.getConversations$default(ConversationRepository.kt:29)
at com.app.sms.feature.main.MainViewModel.<init>(MainViewModel.kt:73)
at com.app.sms.feature.main.MainViewModel_Factory.provideInstance(MainViewModel_Factory.java:189)
at com.app.sms.feature.main.MainViewModel_Factory.get(MainViewModel_Factory.java:122)
at com.app.sms.feature.main.MainViewModel_Factory.get(MainViewModel_Factory.java:28)
at com.app.sms.feature.main.MainActivityModule_ProvideMainViewModelFactory.provideInstance(MainActivityModule_ProvideMainViewModelFactory.java:31)
at com.app.sms.feature.main.MainActivityModule_ProvideMainViewModelFactory.get(MainActivityModule_ProvideMainViewModelFactory.java:26)
at com.app.sms.feature.main.MainActivityModule_ProvideMainViewModelFactory.get(MainActivityModule_ProvideMainViewModelFactory.java:9)
at com.app.sms.common.ViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelFactory.kt:28)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130)
at com.app.sms.feature.main.MainActivity$viewModel$2.invoke(MainActivity.kt:152)
at com.app.sms.feature.main.MainActivity$viewModel$2.invoke(MainActivity.kt:82)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
at com.app.sms.feature.main.MainActivity.getViewModel(Unknown Source:2)
at com.app.sms.feature.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:177)
```

**I'm working on system default app like messages app and all the data is sync with Realm DB. When I make my app as system default app in custom Android OS it throws me this error every time.**

Comment: There's obviously an environment issue but it's not clear how we can help with that?

Comment: I have " jni: ThrowingException 5, Permission denied in /Users/jasonflax/Development/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 101, .
Exception has been thrown: Unrecoverable error. Permission denied in /Users/jasonflax/Development/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 101 " this issue with my app!

Comment: Understood. You clearly have a permissions issue in your development environment, right? There's nothing we can do to help with that as it's unrelated to the code you've written. SO is not a technical support site for your device or OS, we can only help with existing code. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Check again please!

Comment: That looks like the Realm file is open when you're trying to delete it? Any reference to a realm file within the code will create a reference to it and it cannot be deleted in  that case. It's just a guess.